# Cannot download .py file from Notebook

Tags: python, download

I am running Jupyter Notebook 6.1.0 and Python 3.8.5 on Windows 10. I create a simple Python file in Notebook and attempt to Download it as a .py file from the File Menu. Down in the lower left corner of the browser window, it seems to indicate it has saved it as a .py file. But when I click there on Open File, a window opens and immediately closes. If I look at the directory where the .py file should be saved, there is a not a .py file with the expected name. There is only an .ipynb file with that name.

Comment: If I had to make a guess, when you click on it what you're actually doing is executing that script. Try `open with` and select a text editor or IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a python file is saved as a text file in the directory. And the opening and closing is happening because it's  the given output for that.

In Python 3, add the following to the end of your code:

input('Press ENTER to exit')

and open the file in  a pycharm or your IDE edition.